# Registering domains for resale and remain anonymous

Tags: domains, privacy, private-registration

I am sorry if this question has been answered elsewhere, but I cannot find a proper answer.

So, I have reason to believe that a certain domain name, say JOHNDOODLE.com, will be of commercial interest in few months. At the same time, JOHNDOODLE will not be trademarked or anything like that.

I would like to take the chance and register the domain name (and related) and resell it if a buyer contacts me.

Now, I have three questions:

1) Is this a legal operation? 
2) If a buyer approaches me, or even before that, I would like to remain anonymous, being paid but never be traceable (I do not want to be related with JOHNDOODLE.com in any way). I have no problem in paying for the domain with my credit card, but I do not want the buyer or whoever has the same idea to know that I am the owner of the domain name. It is ok if they trace my IP or email, but want to preserve my real name.  I saw some advice about how to remain anonymous,  but would like to have a concrete suggestion about how to proceed. Which register provider and which option to choose?.

Comment: This is a pretty broad and opinion-based question, which reads like a "how to conduct [domain squatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybersquatting) anonymously". You would likely fail all three of the criteria for adjudicating a [UDRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Domain-Name_Dispute-Resolution_Policy), and would expose yourself as the registrant in the process since ICANN can request contact information from ICANN accredited registrars even if done by proxy (aka., private) registration. There is also no guarantee that another party wouldn't file a trademark retroactively either.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Just to clarify, there is not going to be ever a trademark on the domain name, although the other two UDRP criteria could apply. However, its value will not be so high to warrant any legal action through ICANN or other. Just to be concrete. Suppose I buy the name for 100USD I wish to resell it for 1000 usd. It is a bet, and there is the chance that nobody would be interested in it, If  so I ll lose 100 USD which I am willing to do. Many thanks, Jan

Comment: If you think the domain will be worth that much, then why wouldn't someone file a trademark for it too? You're gambling on the hunch that they'll try to negotiate with you, which in most cases they don't. You'll just receive a demand letter from an attorney, like in [this](http://forum.freeadvice.com/copyrights-trademarks-39/can-word-mark-enforced-retroactively-602186.html) example (relayed through your proxy service). You can also run the risk of legal action too, which a private registration won't protect you from. I'd suggest not gambling on domains you don't have a legitimate interest in.